# Adding Jquery and React fb to html file

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Jason.Martin\Documents\ReactTry\ToDo.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="react.min.js"></script>
<script src="JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type='text/jsx'>
var Demo = React.createClass({
render:function(){
  return (
    <div id='bg1'>
    <div id='block1'>
      <h1>Martin Family "To Do" List</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='block3'>
      <input id='txt1' />
      <button id='btn1'>{'Enter'}</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ol id='sortable'>
      </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
);
}
});
var demo = React.createElement(Demo);
React.render(demo, document.body);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src='C:\JS\jq.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn1').click(function() {
   $("ol").append("<li>"+$("#txt1").val()+"</li>");
   $("#txt1").val("").focus();
   $('li').addClass('#block2');
   $('ol').sortable();
   $('li').click(function() {
     $(this).hide(500, function() {
     $(this).remove('li');
   });
 });
});
});
```

It renders fine on Google Chrome with no errors in the dev tools. However - the jquery does not work. I type in some text in the textbox and hit the button but nothing happens. This code is tested without react fb involved and it works just fine. Help please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the button is not rendered when you run the jquery. Instead of doing it like this you should look into how to do the click event with react:

```
var Demo = React.createClass({
buttonClick: function() {
    // do stuff using this.setState(...)
},
render:function(){
  return (
    <div id='bg1'>
    <div id='block1'>
      <h1>Martin Family "To Do" List</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='block3'>
      <input id='txt1' />
      <button id='btn1' onClick={this.buttonClick}>{'Enter'}</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ol id='sortable'>
      </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
);
}
});
```

This is not a complete answer, but from your question I can see that you need to study react a bit. I'll recommend the official guide.

Don't worry, it's worth it! React is pretty cool when you get the hang on it and it will clean up your code and make you fell awesome ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually only 4 months in to learning programming. I learn more by doing, hence asking questions here when I can't find (or understand) the answer on the tutorials and such. My main issue is - I'm learning jquery (after javascript of course) but my friend said I should get used to using react as well as a front end framework. So everything I've seen, it appears that react changes my jquery code as you have shown above. I do need to read up on it more. I would love to hear your 'complete' answer though if you have time.

Comment: I myself learned a lot of what I can today by doing. Like your friend I'll recommend you look into react. I'll actually recommend it over jquery, since it will give you more structure and a modern way of thinking. Jquery is kind of the old web, and has never had much todo with how other programming languages do it. To supplement your learning by doing approach I will recommend you read up on the subject through a good book or real good tutorial. For the complete example, take a look at example two here http://tutorialzine.com/2014/07/5-practical-examples-for-learning-facebooks-react-framework/

Comment: I'll practice more with just javascript and react - however, I was told jquery 'is' javascript and was meant to make writing code easier. A "write less, do more, javascript library" - w3schools.com. Seems you are very knowledgable in areas I want to develop :), hopefully I'll see your responses when I ask more questions later!!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this:

```
React.render(demo, document.body, function() {
    console.log(!!$('#btn1').length); // true
    // Run your jQuery code here
});
```

As this will ensure React will have actually rendered to the DOM before you try to query it with jQuery.

But I really wouldn't recommend this... wherever possible I wouldn't mess with elements 'owned' by React.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got my code to work without the two answers above from Emil Ingerslev and riscarrott. I'm not sure if it was just switching from my 8.1 windows computer to my windows 10 computer with 'edge browser', but here I the code. I reworked the jquery code a little.
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Jason Martin\Documents\TryReact\ToDo.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="react.min.js"></script>
<script src="JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type='text/jsx'>
var Demo = React.createClass({
render:function(){
  return (
    <div id='bg1'>
    <div id='block1'>
      <h1>Martin Family "To Do" List</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='block3'>
      <input id='txt1' />
      <button id='btn1'>{'Enter'}</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ol>
      </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
});
var demo = React.createElement(Demo);
React.render(demo, document.body);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src='C:\JS\jq.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on('click', '#btn1', function() {
    $("ol").append("<li>"+$("#txt1").val()+"</li>");
    $("#txt1").val("").focus();
    $('li').addClass('block2').className;
    $('ol').sortable();
  });
 $(this).on('click', 'li', function() {
   $(this).hide(500, function() {
     $(this).remove('li');
  });
 });
});
```

With my CSS file, everything work great - the only item that works a little funky is the .sortable - when you click to drag, the element appears all the way on the left hand side of the screen and when you release to place your element where you want it, it appears where it should.